# Tracing where a syslog() call comes from

Tags: linux, syslog

Is there a way on a RHEL system to trace back where a syslog() call comes from?

I am getting some weird generic message on my syslog and I have no idea where it is coming from.

Can I modify the main syslog function to output the stack trace when it encounters the log line I am looking for?

How would I go about this?

Comment: Good question but I suspect it is more about system administration than about programming within the [scope defined in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I think it belongs to [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/about).

Comment: If you're on a system that is actually using `journald` you can look at the verbose log to get the pid that logged the message, along with the associated command name.  If you're just running legacy syslog your options aren't so good.

Comment: @PauloScardine Changing the code of `syslog()` is a programming task, not something a sysadmin would typically do.

Comment: @Barmar absolutely correct, a sysadmin would never think of touching syslog sources, he would know how to answer the first question (how to locate the process producing some specific logs) using instrumentation. Obviously the answer to the second question is "yes, it is possible to modify the log daemon if you have the sources" hence I'm ignoring it.

Comment: @PauloScardine I was a sysdmin about 30 years ago, and I often customized vendor code. But I was managing Lisp Machines, which were easier to customize locally than Unix. :)

Comment: @PauloScardine the "main syslog function" (syslog(3)) is not part of the log daemon but part of  libc. Since the OP wants a stacktrace, they may already know the process who logged the "weird message", but not where from in its source. In that case, a solution could be to use a `LD_PRELOAD` hack, but more details and clarifications are needed for a proper answer.

Comment: @mosvy you are correct. I know the process but not where it comes from. What details would you need?